# Logging into websites

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I am trying to run a VB Script that logs into several websites. I can get the first website in the list to login, but am having issues when it opens a new tab and trys the next website. I have verified that the IDs and values are all correct, and that the webpage is loaded before it attempts. It doesn't seem to be able to see the forms and such on that second tab. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
'This is all part of a loop, if it's not the first webpage, it'll open a new tab
   if i = 2 then
      IE.Navigate wp
   else
      IE.Navigate2 wp, 2048
      Wait IE
   end if

'My hack at errorhandling, it has to go through the code at least once
'and THEN fail 5 times before it gives up and quits

errnum = 0
On Error Resume Next
try = 0

do until Err.Number = 0 And try = 1

   try = 1
   if errnum > 5 then
      msgbox "STOPPED"
      objExcel.ActiveWorkBook.Close
      WScript.Quit
   End if

   Wait IE
   Err.Clear

   with IE.Document
      .getElementByID(unid).value = unval
      .getElementByID(pwid).value = pwval
      .getElementByID(but).Click
   End With

   errnum = errnum + 1
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

### Navigate2 creates a new IE object, you have to find it.

Your IE object is only a reference to the first tab. the `Navigate2` method creates a new window, which is not referenced by the IE object.  The new windows can be accessed from the `shell.application` object, but you'll have to identify the correct IE or window to operate on.

```
newIE = getWindow("Title of New Tab")
if isObject(newIE) then
    With newIE.Document
        .getElementByID(unid).value = unval
        .getElementByID(pwid).value = pwval
        .getElementByID(but).Click
    End With
else
    WScript.echo "Window not found"
end if

Function getWindow(sTitle)
    Dim wins, w, result

    set wins = createobject("shell.application").windows
    for i = 1 to 10 ' max iterations before fail
        for each w in wins
            on error resume next
            if instr(1, typename(w.document),"html", vbTextCompare) > 0 then
                if instr(1, w.document.title, sTitle, vbTextCompare) = 1 then
                    set result = w
                    do until w.document.readyState = "complete" : WScript.sleep 50 : loop
                    exit for
                end if
            end if
            on error goto 0
        next
        if isObject(result) then exit for
        WScript.sleep 500 ' ms to wait for each iteration (tab must load before we can get obj)
    next

    if not(isObject(result)) then result = false;
    getWindow = result;

end Function ' getWindow
```

### [EDIT:] Alternate means of locating the correct window

Within the `getWindow()` function, `w` is set as an IE object. Thus, you can redefine the `getWindow()` function to identify the window according to any of the methods available in the [InternetExplorer object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx).

#### Change the comparison conditional in the main `getWindow()` loop.

```
if instr(1, w.document.title, sTitle, vbTextCompare) = 1 then
```

`w` is the window, so:

- Use the [Window.LocationURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa752058(v=vs.85).aspx) property:

  - `if instr(1, w.LocationURL, sURL, vbTextCompare) = 1 then
  - you'll have to define the sURL variable.
- Use the [Window.Document.URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535862(v=vs.85).aspx) property:

  - `if instr(1, w.Document.URL, sURL, vbTextCompare) = 1 then
  - you'll have to define the sURL variable.

Additionally, once you have the window reference `w`, you can do pretty much anything else you want to with the document, like `w.Document.Focus`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I know what goes in the "Title of New Tab"? It's a comcast page, so the blurb that is on the tab itself is "Sign in to Comcast", but that didn't work.   

Is there a way to build a list of open tabs, and find the one that wasn't there before the new one was opened?

Comment: @Jeff you'll have to loop through (as in the `getWindow()` function) and store titles, or references into a separate array. The do a check on each window for if it exists in that array.

Comment: Any new developments?

Comment: I wasn't able to figure it out. I ended doing a work-around where once I reach my destination, I copy the address into a new tab, and the start the next one in the original. It works too! Thank you for you help.